# What image format should be employed for real time processing using Camera2 in android?

Tags: camera, android-camera, opencv3.0, android-camera2

I am developing an android application which processes Camera2 preview frames and displays processed frames on the Texture. At first, I tested with camera1 api, it works fine for real time image processing.

```
private class CameraPreviewCallback implements Camera.PreviewCallback {
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
  processingRunnable.setNextFrame(data, camera);
}
```

}

Then, I changed my code which utilizes camera2 api. For getting preview frames, I set ImageFormat as YUV_420_888

```
    mImageReaderPreview = ImageReader.newInstance(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight(), ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 3);
            mImageReaderPreview.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnPreviewAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);    

private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnPreviewAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                Image mImage = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                if(mImage == null) {
                    return;
                }
           processingRunnable.setNextFrame(convertYUV420888ToNV21(mImage));
                mImage.close();
            }
        };
```

However, it's working slower than camera1. May be it's because of having one extra conversion from YUV_420_888 to NV21. Since Camera1 can directly provides NV21 frame from Camera1.

Answer (score 1):

Conversion could be expensive, depending on how you implement it and what the layout of the YUV_420_888 on a given device is.

Certainly if it's written in pure Java is probably going to be slow.

That said, if the device you're using is at the LEGACY hardware level, camera2 has to run in a legacy mode that can be slow for receiving YUV information.  For those devices, staying on API1 may be preferable for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Image processing part is implemented using opencv c++, but drawing processed frames is on pure java.